# Include module for routed component

Tags: vmware-clarity

Trying to use clarity within a routed component, seeing the error below.
Flow: AppModule > AppComponent > AppRouting > HomeComponent

clr-datagrid succeeds on the AppComponent html, but within the routed HomeComponent fails.

```
ERROR in src/app/components/home.component.html:4:13 - error NG8001: 'clr-datagrid' is not a known element:
    1. If 'clr-datagrid' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'clr-datagrid' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

    4             <clr-datagrid>
```

home.component.html:

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="content-area">
            <clr-datagrid>
            </clr-datagrid>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AppRoutingModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home.component'

const routes: Routes = [{path: "", component: HomeComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

AppComponent:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ClarityModule } from '@clr/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ClarityModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix was in AppModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, HomeComponent
```